# How to properly use encryption with AES?

Tags: javascript, html, aes

I have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="core-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript>" src="sha1.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript>" src="hmac-sha1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript>" src="aes.js"></script>

    <div id="divContent"></div>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

        try{
           var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message for Encrypt", "Pass");
           var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Pass");


          document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        }catch (ex){
            console.log(ex.message);
        }
        });
    </script>
```

And the console gives me this error:

> Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is  having an extra `>`, which won't let read the `src`.

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript>" src="sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>" src="hmac-sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>" src="aes.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hmac-sha1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aes.js"></script>
```

Note the colors from code color

Comment: which dumbest mistake ; but thank you very much

Comment: It happens ;) , you are welcome!